# DolphinDB database select last N rows

Tags: database, select, dolphindb

I have a DolphinDB segment table `t`, and I would like to do a query like this:

```
select LAST N ROWS from t context by sym
```

How do I write this query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A negative limit number in conjunction with context-by clause will output last N rows for each group.

```
select * from t context by sym limit -5
```